# How can I use transparent webm for Android?

Tags: android, transparent, webm, webp

I am trying to use some video resources. And I wanna get rid of the background and change the color as I want.

I used VideoView for easy implementation. However, it gave black background. I don't want that. So, I am trying to use TextureVideoView.

```
implementation 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.2.1'
```

However, when I play the webm files, it seems it's not transparency.

What's the reason???

It's weird because I also exported and played a few clips to Webm with alpha channel. And it gives white or broken color background. (VideoView also gives gray background like this.)

Source Video:
https://simpl.info/videoalpha/video/dancer1.webm, 
https://simpl.info/videoalpha/video/soccer1.webm

(It's totally fine here: https://simpl.info/videoalpha/)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Someone using ExoPlayer attempted the same thing. Perhaps the following might shed some insight if it's even possible. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2509#issuecomment-286516056