# Playing video with alpha channel (transparent background) in exoplayer in compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, transparent

Is it possible to play alpha channel video (Transparent background) in exoplayer in compose android? any workaround? I tried with `TextureView` but it didn't work.
I went thorough all of these link but didn't find any solution.
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2509#issuecomment-286516056

[How can I use transparent webm for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62300799/how-can-i-use-transparent-webm-for-android)

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7789